# How to show a carto map in an ionic 2 app?

Tags: ionic2, cartodb

Has anyone shown a carto map in an ionic 2 app? When I used **ionic 1** there was no problem, because it is **angular js** and I could add the library in the index.html:

and then use it in a controller.js like that:

```
var mapa; mapa = new L.Map('mapa', { center: [39,-6], zoom: 9 })
```

But the problem is that now I'm using **ionic 2**, so it's **angular 2**, typescript. After adding the libraries I try to do the same code above in the .ts file, but it can't find the name L.

Has anyone idea how to show my map? Or how to use a js library in typescript?

I'm not sure if I explained well the problem, so any doubt, ask me please.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

in index.html add this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://libs.cartocdn.com/cartodb.js/v3/3.15/themes/css/cartodb.css">
  <script src="http://libs.cartocdn.com/cartodb.js/v3/3.15/cartodb.js"></script>
```

in page.ts file add this:

```
import L from 'leaflet';
```

and alsodeclare L for avoiding from that error:

declare var L: any;

Comment: I've only put a piece of code but L is not the only element I need. I also need cartodb: `cartodb.createLayer(mapa, layerUrl)
        .addTo(mapa)
        .on('done', function(layer) {});` Could I do the same with that? @coenni

Comment: i havent used cartodb, maybe same strategy or without ever declaring it can work. have you tried?

Comment: I have asked this question in other pages, and finally I used the answer of this one:
https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/76234/c%C3%B3mo-mostrar-un-mapa-de-carto-en-ionic-2-o-angular-2
That works for me. It's similar to yours but it includes cartodb objetc and the import it's not necesary. Thanks! @coenni